# Nav inside Header, Position Fixed?

Tags: css, css-position

I have an header with 100% width, and a nav inside header with 980px

Now i want to give the position as fixed for both header and nav.
I have tried with the following code but could'nt get what i wanted to
Please help me,

my header.css

```
width:100%;
height:60px;
background: #ffffff;
position:fixed;
z-index:999;`
```

and my nav.css

```
background: #ffffff;
height: 60px;
text-align:center;
position:fixed;
z-index:99;
```

.nav ul

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

.nav li

```
   display: inline-block;
   list-style-type: none;
   vertical-align:middle;`
```

.nav li a

```
font-size: 16px;
color: black;
display: block;
line-height: 60px;
padding: 0 10px;
text-decoration: none;
```

Comment: Really hard to help without more code, such as your html. If you can reproduce your layout at codepen.io or jsfiddle.net, it would help. That said, only your `header` should have `position: fixed` - the `nav` will stay put because it's nested inside the `header`.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart Thanks for ur reply, html of header and nav part or complete layout html?? i could'nt understand can u elaborate please .

Comment: @Fastnto : A fiddle would be great,if you can provide one..

Comment: Relevant parts - just the header and nav should be enough.

Comment: I donno wats going wrong but some how i put it in fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/j2hC9/) i know that looks complete odd, please help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 0):

If the nav is inside the header you don't need `position:fixed` in your nav.css, you should also remove the z-index. A clearer description of the problem and the html you're using would be helpful if that doesn't help.

Comment: Thank for ur reply Does **Position:fixed** problem has any link with nav of ul li a tags??

Comment: You only need `position:fixed` on the parent element, in this case, the header. `z-index` shouldn't be necessary either, remove those and see what happens. The `ul li a` part of your code looks fine and shouldn't be causing a problem.

Comment: May be ur answer is fine, but my main page have lost scroll bar now to check the header section, it have content to scroll but no scroll bar.

Comment: I've edited your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2hC9/2/). All I've done is remove the fixed height on the `nav` and added a `.content` div to demonstrate how to position content below the `header`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Or use @alexandre solution but change `.content` from `margin-top:80px;` to `padding-top:80px;`. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@Fastnto, it's something like this that you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/alexandrecanijo/NBp8F/

I've changed some parts of your original CSS in order to show the header (#ccccccc) and nav (#000000) and added the .content with enough lorem ipsum so that you are able to see the nav.
But, the CSS might be cleaned and refactored in some parts... Didn't had a change to do this...

Hope this helps.

```
html,body, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: 14px arial;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background: #cccccc;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:999;
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
    top: 0;
}

.nav {
    background: #000000;
    height: 60px;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:99;
}

.nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.nav li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fe6700;
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    background: #fe6700;
}
.content {
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for ur reply **@alexandre** ur fiddle looks fine for me but that didnt solved my problm completely. It has got around 600px height above my header i donno wer it went wrong. And the position:fixed hav no influence as its going up after scrolling.

Comment: Can you had an example on fiddle to see the HTML and CSS?